# Java Authentication and Authorization

Tags: java, authentication

Can anyone comment on this scenario belong to authentication or authorization

Authentication : User is logging with username & password - called authentication.

Authorization : User has some role - called authorization.

If I have only username and user Id and want to check from DB what it called ? Authorization or Authentication ?

Could anyone comment on this ?

Thanks

Comment: from database point of view a valid user has authorization to access data and Authentication is a feature to validate a user using some unique data

Comment: Thanks . but if I dont have password & want to check the username and userid is present in DB or not - what will be this case. is it the authentication or authorization ??

Comment: neither , it's called verification (assuming are a admin or something ) and your question is has no coding problem it's more like tech grammar so SO community may not like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is the check if someone is the person he/she says he/she is (e.g. by asking for a *password*).
Authorization is the check if someone has the right to do something.

So in your case that database isn't able to check authentication. If the information about what the user is allowed to do can be extracted from the data within the database then this'd be **authorization**.